# Changing MIDI instrument in Java

Tags: java, midi

I'm almost completely unfamiliar with `MIDI`.  I have the need to play a short `MIDI` file from a `Java` application.  That part is working.  However, it's playing with what sounds like an electric piano.  Other applications I have allow me to choose a particular instrument and render the `MIDI` file with that sound.

If I've misunderstood what is possible in `MIDI`, please correct me.

If I haven't, I'd like to change to `Instrument 22`.  I can't figure out how to do this and the answers I've found for existing questions here seem incomplete, assuming information not found in the answer.

I boiled that part of my application down to a minimal sample to show what I'm trying:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequencer;

public class TryMidi
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            sequencer.open();

            InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("test.mid")));

            sequencer.setSequence(stream);
            sequencer.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

What do I do before calling `"sequencer.start()"` to `switch` the instrument?

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the API, I don't think you can do that.  It looks like you would need to edit the MIDI Event sequence for the track.

Comment: I was REALLY hoping someone wouldn't say that. *smile*

Comment: I could be wrong :-)

Comment: You could send a Program Change message before sending the sequence, but this does not help if the MIDI file then explicitly sets the piano.

Comment: I'll look into how to do that and see if it changes anything.